# Yii functional testing is not working with phpunit

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

Phpunit is working correctly in a basic project but when I try to use in yii functional test, I get this error:
**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_Warning::setupSpecificBrowser() in ~/phpunit/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumBrowserSuite.php on line 95**

I installed phpunit using composer. Version: PHPUnit 4.0.17 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Selenium version: 2.41.0

I run selenium like this: **java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar**

I run test class like this: **~/phpunit/vendor/bin/phpunit functional/SiteTest.php**

In basic project code:

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertEquals('Title string', $this->title());
    }

}
```

Yii code:

```
class WebTestCase extends CWebTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->setBrowserUrl(Yii::app()->params['url']['base']);
    }
}
```

Also **CWebTestCase** class exteds **PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase** class, not **PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase**.

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on the version of PHPUnit. I know that Yii 1.1.x has problems with latest versions of PHPUnit and you have to install an old one.

You can do it in two ways:

PEAR (deprecated):

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.7.1
sudo pear install phpunit/DbUnit
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_Invoker
```

Composer (better):

create a `composer.json` file, put it in `protected` with this content:

```
{                                                                                                                                        
  "require" : {
      "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.x-dev"
      "phpunit/dbunit": "1.3.*@dev",
      "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "dev-master",
      "phpunit/phpunit-story": "dev-master",
      "phpunit/php-invoker": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

and run `composer install`.

If you go for composer, remember that you have to add `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');` in your classes and that PHPUnit binaries will be in `protecte/vendor/bin`

Comment: Instead of adding the "require_once" on my classes, i replace the last lines of the index.php of the root directiry with this :

`require_once($yii);
`$loader        = require(`__DIR`__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
`Yii::$classMap = $loader->getClassMap();
`Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for a different reason. My test file contained a private method whose name started with "test". I changed the method name to something else (because it wasn't meant to be a phpunit/selenium test) and it worked fine. It also ran fine when I set it to public.

It doesn't look like this was the problem for the original poster, but I figured I'd put this here in case anyone else had my same problem.